# react-select vs react-select/creatable

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I want to ask I have a big codebase and we're using react-select also sometimes with a creatable option.

The question is when we are using react-select/creatable do I need to use both or just creatable?

Answer (score 0):

`react-select/creatable` lets you create an option if it does not exist.

EDIT:

short answer: use both of those depending on your needs.
if you need a creatable option, have to use `react-select/creatable` otherwise react-select is what you need.

Comment: I exactly wrote that :) my question if I should use both or I can just use react-select/creatable all the time